# Why is my get() method failing for this function?

Tags: java, opencv

I'm currently working on a piece of code which turns an image to greyscale, using OpenCV. I've managed to turn the image black and white, as I wanted, with the following code:

```
 public static void Greyscale() {

    Mat inputImage = Highgui.imread("files/lena.png");
    Mat greyImage = new Mat();
    Imshow ims4 = new Imshow("Grey Image");
    Imgproc.cvtColor(inputImage, greyImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    ims4.showImage(greyImage);
```

However, I now want to run a get() method on some particular pixels to make sure that all the BGR values are equal. However, that doesn't work:

```
double[] bgr = greyImage.get(0, 0);
System.out.println( "colour @ (0,0) = B: " + bgr[0] + " G: " + bgr[1] + " R: " + bgr[2]);
```

Running the code above leads to error messages like "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at ColourQuery.Greyscale(ColourQuery.java:129)
    at ColourQuery.main(ColourQuery.java:67)"

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong with this code? It worked for the image when it wasn't greyscale...

Comment: What is the size of `greyImage`? Do you have anything is it?

Comment: how many channels are in a grayscale image ? look at it again ..

Comment: It's the same size as inputImage, which the get() code worked for.

Comment: only bgr[0] is valid in the grayscale case, the other 2 are out of bounds. (also, misleading var-name probably already fooled you ;)

Comment: Uhhh, sorry. Why is it only bgr[0] which is valid here? I thought all three values would be the same. Also, which variable is misleading? Sorry for the rookie questions...

Comment: Grayscale images don't have red, green, blue components.  Only a value representing how black or white it is.

Comment: Oh, I thought they did, they were just all equal...

Answer (score 1):

not all images have the same number of channels, maybe you need a conditional:

```
double[] pixel = img.get(0, 0);
switch( img.channels() ) {
    case 1: // grayscale, luminance only
        System.out.println( "colour @ (0,0) = L: " + pixel[0]);
        break;
    case 3: // bgr
        System.out.println( "colour @ (0,0) = B: " + pixel[0] + " G: " + pixel[1] + " R: " + pixel[3]);
        break;
    case 4: // bgra
        System.out.println( "colour @ (0,0) = B: " + pixel[0] + " G: " + pixel[1] + " R: " + pixel[3]+ " A: " + pixel[3]);
        break;
}
```